# Drawable Folder For Tablet Landscape Mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make my app compatible across different devices, the problem is that I need to have a drawable folder (that contains images) for tablet devices but in `landscape` mode. Currently i have a folder for `drawable-large-hdpi`, would anyone know the right one for landscape tablets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `drawable-large-land-hdpi` for tablet devices in landscape mode.

If you are using Android Studio, when adding new drawable (or any other resource) it will show you convenient dialog where you can set different qualifiers.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After Android 3.0 version. You need add smaller screen width for Tablet. [Ref Here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali)

[image]